# I am running Ubuntu server off of an old laptop - if I leave it on and the battery drains to 0%, will it be able to recharge?

Tags: 22.04, battery

I have a Pentium laptop which usually overheats when I run Windows, so I got a new laptop and decided to run a cloud service from the old laptop. I installed Ubuntu Server on it, and I want to know whether Ubuntu Server has any kind of battery management system to protect my laptop battery.

Comment: "*...and the battery drains to 0%, will it be able to recharge?*" That seems a hardware question. The answer will depend more upon your battery and upon the manufacturer's hardware power management than upon the OS

Answer (score 3):

Use the power adapter when you can. This will help to prolong the life of your battery.

---

Ubuntu has several battery management tools that can help protect your laptop's battery from running down to 0%.

- **Power Management:** Ubuntu's default power management settings are designed to optimize battery life. You can further customize these settings in the *Power* section of the Settings app.
- **Powertop:** Powertop (`sudo apt install powertop`) is a command-line tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and  power management. In addition to being a diagnostic tool, Powertop also has an interactive mode you can use to experiment with various power management settings for cases where the Ubuntu has not enabled those settings.
- **TLP:** TLP (`sudo apt install tlp`) is a command-line tool that provides more advanced power management options. TLP’s default settings are already optimized for battery life and implement Powertop's recommendations out of the box. Moreover TLP is highly customizable to fulfill specific user requirements.